# Java: do something if regex not found

Tags: java, regex

I'm parsing log files, and need to do one thing when a regex is found (add ',TRUE' to a variable, .csv, ArrayList), and something else (add an empty slot, "," or ",_" if an empty slot isn't good) when that regex is not found.

There can be 1-~200 entries being parsed from each log file - so the regex could match none-to-several times.

I've tried several options, either get an error on compile (not liking testing a Boolean against a string), no observable action occurs, or when the regex is found I get the result for when regex not found.

I need the output in a variable, .csv or an ArrayList, so if a match is not found, then I need an empty ',' because the output is a pre-defined table, so the columns need to align properly.

Combos I've tried:

```
if(!noBaseText.equals("No matching base data found"))
if(!noBaseText.equals("No matching base data found") == false)
if(noBaseText.equals("No matching base data found" != true))
if(noBaseText.isEmpty())
if(noBaseText.equals(""))
if(!noBaseText.equals(""))
if(noBaseText.equals("No matching base data found"))
```

'} else {' and '} else if (...) {' with the combos above, both when a nested if/else (as in code below) or as an 'else' to the 'if (baseMatcher.find())' return identical results.

Code Snippet:

```
Pattern noBase = Pattern.compile("(?<noBase>No matching base data found)");
try(corrReader)
            {
                while ((corrLine = corrReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    corrText = corrLine.trim();
                    Matcher baseMatcher = noBase.matcher(corrText);
                    if (baseMatcher.find()) 
                    {
                        String noBaseText = baseMatcher.group("noBase");
                        if(!noBaseText.equals("No matching base data found"))
                        {
                            corrOutput += ",";
                        } else if(noBaseText.equals("No matching base data found")) {
                            corrOutput += ",TRUE";
                        } //end else
                    } //end if(baseMatcher)
                } //end while(corrLine)
            } //end try(corrReader)
```

The output I'm getting when there is a match:

> AA-123-12345-SP1.SSF,TRUE,

The output I'm getting when there isn't a match:

> AA-123-12345-SP2.SSF,100,100,guug04314054.zip,

The output I need to get when there isn't a match:

> AA-123-12345-SP2.SSF,,100,100,guug04314054.zip,

When the regex matches, and ',TRUE' is returned, there will be no following entries; when the regex does not match and a ',' is returned, there will be additional entries.

Comment: isn't the result of `find()` enough? why *check* the group?

Comment: BTW if `find()` returns `true`, the group will always be that text, so you will never get `","`.  try just `corrOutput += baseMatcher.find() ? "TRUE," : ",";` or, `if (baseMatcher.find()) { corrOutput += "TRUE,"; } else { corrOutput += ","; }`

Comment: @Carlos Hueberger The output is a .csv, so the column for that field is left off when not true, it throws the columns off when imported into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Carlos Hueberger I gave your suggestions a shot, but there was no change in results.
Thanks for your help, tho!!

Comment: use only the result of `find()`; do **not use** the `group(...)`

Comment: All: Thanks for your help!! With further development, I put the regex matches into an ArrayList of ArrayLists, and from there it was relatively straightforward to add an empty element to correspond to the column where 'TRUE,' was originally being appended. The output is intended to be in tabular format, so each value needs a column, even if the regex wasn't matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator to accomplish this:

```
boolean found = false;
while ((corrLine = corrReader.readLine())!=null)
{
  ...
      String noBaseText = baseMatcher.group("noBase");
      found |= noBaseText.equals("No matching base data found");
  ...
}

corrOutput += found ? "TRUE," :  ",";
```

If the `found` evaluates to true, you'll get `"TRUE,"` otherwise `","`.

Comment: I get the same behavior when adding the first snippet, but when I add the else to baseMatcher, I get lots of spurious commas in the output - my hunch is due to the while loop iterating over 25 entries, only 1 of which should return 'TRUE'.

Comment: Ahh, if you want an aggregation (`TRUE,` if found in any of the 25 records, `,` otherwise), then you'll want a boolean variable to track whether it's been find in the loop.  You'll want to |= rather than appending within your loop, then append based on the value of your variable at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got this right, but.. if you want to check if pattern is empty, do the following:

```
if(noBase.pattern().isEmpty()) {
// do your stuff
}
```

Comment: `pattern()` sould be returning just the regex used in the constructor...